# What is the correct formula of the kernel of the A$^*$A

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators, integral-operators

If the kernel of the linear integral operator A on L$^2$(0,1) where A is a linear bounded integral operator non self adjoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the order of multiplication is taken. For example,
suppose $A$ is of the form $Af(x)=\int_{(0,1]}f(s)k(x,s)\,ds$. Then, by Fubini's theorem
$$\begin{align}
\langle A^*Af,g\rangle&=\langle Af, Ag\rangle=\int_{(0,1]}Af(x)\overline{Ag(x)}\,dx\\
&=\int_{(0,1]}\Big(\int_{(0,1]}f(s)k(x,s)\,ds\Big)\Big(\int_{(0,1]}\overline{g(t)k(x,t)}\,dt\Big)\,dx\\
&=\int_{(0,1]}\Big(\int_{(0,1]\times(0,1]}f(s)k(x,s)\overline{k(x,t)}\,ds\otimes dx\Big)\overline{g(t)}\,dt
\end{align}$$
From this, it follows that
$$\begin{align}
A^*Af(t)&=\int_{(0,1]\times(0,1]} f(s)k(x,s)\overline{k(x,t)}\,dsdx\\
&=\int_{(0,1]}f(s)\Big(\int_{(0,1]}k(x,s)\overline{k(x,t)}\,dx\Big)\,ds
\end{align}$$
Hence, $A^*A$ is of the for $A^*Af(t)=\int_{(0,1]}f(s)\,q(t, s)\,ds$ where
$$q(t, s)=\int_{(0,1]}k(x,s)\overline{k(x,t)}\,dx, \qquad 0<s, t\leq 1$$

When $k(x,s)=\{s/x\}$, then
$$q(t, s)=\int_{(0,1]}\{s/x\}\,\{t/x\}\,dx, \qquad 0<s, t\leq 1$$

When $k(x,s)=\{x/s\}$, then
$$q(t, s)=\int_{(0,1]}\{x/s\}\,\{x/s\}\,dx, \qquad 0<s, t\leq 1$$

The *computation* of these integrals are left to the OP.

---

Comment: Thank you very much. So, please correct me if I am wrong:  q(t,s) the kernel function of (A$^*$A).  In the case when $k(x,s)=\{x/s\}$ is that correct the missing of the variable t in q(t,s) ?